# Where does Cyanogen Mod store boot animations?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod, boot-animation

I am aware that the active boot animation (one being used currently) is stored at `/system/media/bootanimation.zip` but where are the ones stored that get previewed at Settings->Themes->Bootanimations?

Kind Regards

Comment: AFAIK boot animations are Linux executable binaries, not zip archives.

Comment: uhmmm no, on android they are run of the mill zip archives with a series of images and a text file describing frame rate and resolution. Downloading some from http://www.bhoot.co.uk/ wil confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

In CyanogenMod Themes, the bootanimations are stored inside the package of the theme. So, if you want the bootanimation of a particular theme, then just use any archive manager and extract the theme.apk.